# Como criar ficheiro .csv com os dados de outro ficheiro .csv em Python?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, numpy

Boa tarde. Neste momento estou a desenvolver um trabalho de Python que envolve manipulação de ficheiros CSV, e surgiu o seguinte problema:

Ao tentar colocar no 2º ficheiro csv uns dados do 1º ficheiro csv, o resultado é o seguinte:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Os dados do 1º ficheiro CSV são os seguintes:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O objetivo era colocar todos os dados alinhados conforme o cabeçalho.
O meu código é o seguinte:

```
import csv
from operator import index
from pickle import FALSE
from numpy import append
import pandas as pd

tabela = pd.read_csv("alunos.csv", sep=";")

row_list = [["nota_da_1_freq", "nota_da_2_freq", "nota_trabalho", "nota_1_miniteste", "nota_2_miniteste", "nota_3_miniteste", "class_final"],
              [tabela['nota_1F'], tabela['nota_2F'], tabela['nota_TP'], tabela['nota_1MT'], tabela['nota_2MT'], tabela['nota_3MT']]]

with open('class.csv', 'w') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    writer.writerow(row_list)
```

Agradeço a quem me possa ajudar.

Answer (score -2):

De forma simples:

1. Crie as novas colunas no seu dataframe
2. Ordene as colunas
3. Salve o dataframe

### Passo 1:

```
tabela["nova_coluna1"] = "Valor"
tabela["nova_coluna2"] = "Outro Valor"
```

### Passo 2:

```
colunas = ["coluna1", "coluna2", "nova_coluna1", "coluna3", "coluna4", "nova_coluna2"]
tabela = tabela.loc[:, colunas]
```

### Passo 3:

```
tabela.to_csv("/path/para/o/arquivo.csv", index=False)
```